# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} ( \frac{1}{x-\sin x}\int_{0}^{x}t\sin t \text{d}t)$

Tags: integration, limits

Evaluate

$$\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{1}{(x-\sin x)}\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}t\sin t  \text{d}t$$

I know about limits and I also know about integrals but combining them in this form is confusing

the only thing I can say about this expression is that as x approaches zero , the upper bound of the integral will become zero and then the whole expression will be zero !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: Use L'Hopitals rule:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x t \sin t dt = x \sin x $$

by the fundamental theorem of calculus and

$$ \frac{d}{dx}(x - \sin x) = 1 - \cos x$$

And $\frac{ x \sin x}{ 1 - \cos x } $ is of the form $0/0$ as $x \to 0 $ so we have to use $L'hopitals$ again:

Comment: Correct, it is going to be 2 ! Thanks

Comment: Or multiply numerator and denominator by $1+\cos x$, getting $x(1+\cos x)/\sin x$ that's elementary.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: L'hopitale rule does the trick !

Answer (score 1):

here is the limit without l'hospitals. i will use $$\sin x = x - x^3/6 + \cdots$$

then we have $$x - \sin x = x^3/6 + \cdots, \int_0^x t\sin t \, dt = x^3/3+\cdots .$$ therefore the $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac 1 {x - \sin x}  \int_0^x t\sin t \, dt = 2.$$